# How to install postgresql-server-dev-9.4 from source code (postgresql-9.4.6.tar.gz) on Ubuntu 14

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-14.04, libraries, postgresql-9.4

I need to install postgresql-server-dev-9.4 from source, i.e. from postgresql-9.4.6.tar.gz.  And not through:
    `$ sudo apt-get install postgresql-server-dev-9.5`

Any pointers will be appreciated.

(I was able to successfully install libpq-dev from source (postgresql-9.4.6.tar.gz).  But not able to install postgresql-server-dev)

Comment: why, installing from source is so ninties? is there any specfic reason for this?

Comment: Hi. I have to install pgpool-II's pgpool-recovery. But that needs a dependency postgresql-server-dev. And since its a boshrelease (https://bosh.io/docs/release.html), its recommended to install everything (including all dependencies) through source.

Comment: Just grap a tarball, unpack it; run ./configure --prefix=/somewhere; make install; +add a startup file to /etc/init.d; edit postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf. Or read the instructions in the tarball  first.